# How to turn off MAC Address Broadcast

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-adapter

My router detects a MAC address broadcast from my computer every two minutes. I checked Wireshark and found out that my PC sends a MAC address broadcast to the network every two minutes. This broadcast is only sent by my computer and no other client. I know that a broadcast is important, but I am surprised that only my computer as the only client sends this broadcast as a MAC address with it.

Is there any way to disable this MAC address broadcast in Windows 10 and use IP broadcast instead?

[The Content of the Frame looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmTrL.png)

Comment: If you are looking at the MAC address inside a packet, that cannot be turned off. Check your router Wireless Security settings that MAC is not being broadcast that way.

Comment: Why and how is your router detecting that? Why is your router making an issue out of it?

Comment: The Routers Firewall is giving me an Intruder Warning because a Device did a Mac Address broadcast within the network. And because my Computer is the only client that sends a mac broadcast, and this every 2 minutes. Because it sends it too often, he is warning me.

Comment: so what are the contents of those frames?

Comment: We can't tell what your router is complaining about, because "MAC address broadcast" is not a proper name for any kind of known packet. We need more details of what your router really means. Did you copy the message exactly?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the content of the frame in my post above. Here is a Screenshot of the Warning I get: https://i.imgur.com/5BB68dt.png. The text is German and means: Packet of protocol 139 from 0.0.0.0:0 to 255.255.255.255:0 - packet rejected

Comment: your image shows an UDP datagram for port 54915 to all LAN hosts. do you have a piece of Logitech software called Arx installed? the internet reports that it behaves as you describe?

Comment: The Netbios protocol uses LAN broadcasts on UDP\139, and if you have enabled Netbios over TCP\IP, its targets will be 0.0.0.0. I think the packet you showed is not the packet the router is warning you about.

Comment: I use the Logitech G HUB Software for my Mouse and Keyboard. I disabled the ARX Control in the Settings of Logitech G HUB and NetBIOS over TCP/IP in the Windows Ethernet Adapter settings. Still no change.

Comment: I have found another frame from the same time: https://i.imgur.com/8YpCJge.png. This uses ARP as protocol. I don't have other frames captured with Wireshark around the time the router reported the warning

Comment: ARP is a IP-layer technology (layer3) which requires L2 broadcast to function properly. it cannot be disabled. I'd check the German speaking internet on precisely what "protocol 139" means contextually.